# Where are the TimeMachine Backup snapshots in Terminal on macOS Ventura?

Tags: command-line, time-machine, filesystem, apfs, ventura

I have set up a new Apple Silicon Mac and attached an external drive as Time Machine.

The Time Machine drive I can see in Terminal as

```
$ ls -1 /Volumes
...
Persistently
...
```

And in Finder I can in the drive `Persistently` see all the individual snapshots as folders:

[image: Time machine in Finder]

However, in the Terminal, when I list the folders under `Persistently`, I get only:

```
$ ls -1 /Volumes/Persistently
2024-03-30-201433.previous
backup_manifest.plist
```

Where are the snapshots folders?

On my old Mac (running Catalina), I always could see the snapshots folders in Terminal and work through some of the files with Unix commands.

How do I do this now in Ventura?

Comment: What is problem you are trying to solve by viewing TM snapshots with `ls`?

Answer (score 2):

Your new backups are using APFS format, the old ones were HFS+. This has brought a major change to Time Machine in terms of how to find the backups and, more importantly, much increased reliability.

The most recent backup snapshot is mounted at `/Volumes/<TMdisk>` and this is what you are seeing with `ls -1 /Volumes/<TMdisk>`.

All backup snapshots are mounted under `/Volumes/.timemachine/<GUID>` where the GUID is a string of hex digits and hyphens. You can see all the mounted snapshots with the command `mount | sort`.

Then use `ls -la /Volumes/.timemachine/<GUID>/<date-time>.backup` and drill down to get to your files.

In my view, using the command line is not an efficient way of viewing backup snapshots. Using Finder is so much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. However it doesn't work for me completely. I _do_ see the backups under `/Volumes/.timemachine/<>GUID>/`, e.g. `/Volumes/.timemachine/<GUID>/2024-03-14-123547.backup` and I can see inside that a `Data` directory, but when I try to look into the Data directory with  `ls -a /Volumes/.timemachine/<GUID>/2024-03-14-123547.backup/Data` I get an "No such file or directory" error. So no snapshot is there!

Comment: @halloleo Under `/Volumes/.timemachine` are mount points from all/most TM backups. The mount points for 'thinned' backups are still there, but don't have anything mounted.  That is why I suggested using `mount` to discover the backups which are mounted.  If the backups are not mounted you can a) open them in Finder or b) Disk Utility with View > Show APFS snapshots.